# Fast per-pixel blend effect "multiply" in C# (for android)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin, porter-duff

I've been looking around for a faster way to use the blend effect "multiply" on my bitmaps. I have tried using `PorterDuff.Multiply` but it doesn't achieve the desired result on bitmaps that contain Alpha channels, anything with 0 alpha becomes black.

I've read around and it seems the only way I can achieve the effect I'm after (photoshop/gimp's 'multiply' layer blending) is by applying the effect per pixel.

OpenGL is not an option for the App.

I'm not sure if I understand the algorithm properly for the blend mode suggested by Wikipedia.

`TopColour * BottomColour / 255`

Would be:

```
ColorC.R = ColorA.R * ColorB.R / 255;
ColorC.G = ColorA.G * ColorB.G / 255;
ColorC.B = ColorA.B * ColorB.B / 255;
// Alpha = Alpha?

// This example is suggesting Android.Graphics.Color.A/R/G/B is writeable, 
// it's not - this is just for readability.
// ColorA = Top, ColorB = Bottom, ColorC = Result
```

Would it be faster to convert the `Color.ToArgb` and work with the integer?
And finally, am I calculating the multiply effect correctly - it doesn't display properly :(

I'm stuck, any help would be **greatly** appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This article might shed some light http://kevindion.com/2011/01/android-bitmap-blending-color-channels/

Comment: I think the hint to this is to use ARGB_8888 mode, this way you will be able to blend Alpha values as well.

Comment: @auselen thank you! Reading that shed some light on my clouded mind. I understand a lot more about the blending process because of that small article. Nice find!.

Comment: @Cheesebaron With the multiply blend mode, would Alpha be multiplied also? `ColorC.A = ColorA.A * ColorB.A / 255;` I'll give that a go! :) Thank you. (or will I need to multiply the Alpha by each other color channel first? >< that's where I'm confused lol).

Answer (score 0):

If you want fast, you need to look into Renderscript, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html .

This video from Google also shows you more or less everything you need, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbQb1PVjfqM (Google IO 2012 - Doing More With Less: Being a Good Android Citizen).

Comment: I did not know about renderscript, this will definitely come in handy. And I need to watch that video - bookmarked at the start of my toolbar. Thank you.